# Why i can not get the context (proc) of a block?

Tags: ruby

I have this builder with this class i am creating an proc with adding values

```
class MyBuilder
    attr_reader :values
  
    def initialize(something)
      @something = something
      @values = {}
    end
  
    def inner(name, &block)
      @values[name] = block 
    end
end
```

to get the proc i am using this function instance_exec

```
require './my_builder'
class Out 
    def self.outer(sth, builder, &block)
        builder.instance_exec(&block) 
        p "result", builder.values
    end
end
```

when i tested with this worked very well, this is the answer `:oneone` which is correct

```
Out.outer(:hello, builder) do
            builder.inner(:one) { :oneone }
        end
```

but with this not worked, this is the input, only i am trying to get the block `do event :assign do ...`

```
#   datan status: {unassigned: 0, assigned: 1, resolved: 2} do
#     event :assign do
#       transition :unassigned => :assigned
#     end
#   end

def self.datan(name = nil, values = nil, **options, &block)
# options is {unassigned: 0, assigned: 1, resolved: 2}
# block should `do event :assign do ...`

Out.outer(:hello, builder) do
            builder.inner(:one) { block }
        end
```

Comment: &block turns the Proc into a block, and you never #call your Proc. What exactly are you trying to do this way, and why?

Comment: "not worked" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: _"this not worked"_ – that's a very vague error description. What is your expected result for the second one, and why?

Comment: @SnnyPictures you accepted Todd’s answer so I assume your problem got resolved?

Comment: You'd probably be better off just building your objects **as real objects** and storing them in a Struct, Array, Hash, or Data object rather than passing around closures to build them at runtime. It's unclear why you're trying to do that, so unless you have a *really* good reason just build real objects with your builder rather than trying to write clever metaprogramming structures. They're hard to debug, especially if you don't use good tests and very traceable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

There's a lot wrong with what you're trying to do, so I'm not going to try to explain it line-by-line or debug your code. Instead, I'll lead off simply by saying that your biggest two issues are:

1. [Proc](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Proc.html) objects are closures, so the [Binding](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Binding.html) isn't necessarily what you think it is when called from outside the class or binding where it was created.
2. Procs and lambdas provide some neat tricks, but you can do most of what you'd do with them as methods. Don't make your code over-complicated. The "simplest things that could possibly work" is almost always better than clever code.

That said, here's a working example where anonymous blocks are defined outside the class, converted to procs, stored in an instance variable as a collection of named procs, and then called by name with [Proc#call](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Proc.html#method-i-call). It works for me on Ruby 3.2.2, so feel free to adapt as needed for your own use case.

#### Example Code in `foo.rb`

```rb
class MyBuilder
  attr_reader :procs

  def initialize
    @procs = {}
    @binding = binding
  end 

  def merge name, &block
    fail ArgumentError, "no block given" unless block_given?
    hash = { name => block }
    @procs.merge!(hash)
  end 

  alias_method :push, :merge

  def call_block name
    $stderr.printf "Calling %p ... ", name
    pp @procs[name].call
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  b = MyBuilder.new
  b.push("hi") { "Hello!" }
  b.push("bye") { "Goodbye!" }

  # inspect the @procs instance variable
  $stderr.printf "%p\n\n", b.procs

  b.procs.keys.each { b.call_block _1 }
end
```

#### Example Output from `foo.rb`

```
~> ruby foo.rb
{"hi"=>#<Proc:0x00000001051e9118 foo.rb:25>, "bye"=>#<Proc:0x00000001051e9078 foo.rb:26>}

Calling "hi" ... "Hello!"
Calling "bye" ... "Goodbye!"
```

Comment: @ToddAJacobs i got this: `#<Proc:0x00005632f3ff1730 hola.rb:15>` its ok?

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge but this `do
#     event :assign do
#       transition :unassigned => :assigned
#     end
#   end ` is this `#<Proc:0x00005632f3ff1730 hola.rb:15>` right?

Comment: @SnnyPictures When you inspect an object like a Proc, you're going to get a unique hex number. It doesn't matter if your numbers are different from mine or identical Procs on your machine; that's to be expected because they're different objects. Whether or not you can get this to work the way you want is a *scope* problem, which I tried to explain. If my solution is working for you, great. If not, try simpler data structures and use standard methods instead of procs and lambdas; trying to do this with closures is inherently challenging, and unlikely to be worth the effort.